# Codeigniter server root

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, upload, path

I am trying to upload video in server using Codeigniter, In the localhost i can do it, but when in the server it does not work. Even though `do_upload()`  function returns true.

When i'm testing the server root,    `print_r($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`  it returns

`/var/www/mjpp/data/www/supps.mydomainname.com`

Also the
`$updata = $this->upload->data();` returns

`[file_path] => /var/www/mjpp/data/www/supps.mydomainname.com/public/video`

Can you tell me why `/var/www/mjpp/data/` is appearing before my main domain name , and is it the cause of any error for uploading video?

Thank you in advance, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

`/var/www/mjpp/data/www/supps.mydomainname.com` is absolute location of your document root in a system in general. However you do not usually have access to anything above your user dir.

`public/video` or `/var/www/mjpp/data/www/supps.mydomainname.com/public/video` (as absolute path) is what you pass to `Upload` library as `upload_path`. This is where the library will try yo upload the files. This folder should exist and be writeable (have 0777 permissions on it for example).

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Document Root, Codeigniter itself having configurations when file uploading.

Here is sample code for image uploading,

```
function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

You just need to change the configuration($config array), for your issue you should use the $config['upload_path'].

Follow codigniter file upload [tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: Thanks, but i need to know why /var/www/mjpp/data/ is appearing before my main domain name. Can you you tell me please.

Comment: Document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file. So that is how they configure in real server, You doesn't get dedicated space , you have shared space with other.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in CI, use URL Helper

```
$this->load->helper('url');

echo base_url();
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I use `base_url()` for file path like `base_url()images/upload/path/`   ?

Comment: Yes but create $path=base_url().'images/upload/path/';